# PHP Arrays: Loop through array with a lot of conditional statements

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know how to get it to work the best way.

I need to loop through an array like the one below. I need to check if the [country] index is equal to a Spanish speaking country (lot of countries I predefine) and then get those [title] indexes of the correspondent country, check for duplicates and create new more compact and simplified array.

The original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Jeux de pouvoir 
            [country] => France
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Los secretos del poder
            [country] => Argentina
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Los secretos del poder 
            [country] => Mexico
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => El poder secreto 
            [country] => Uruguay
        )
)
goes on and on....
```

To help you understand, the final result I need to get looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Los secretos del poder
            [country] => Argentina, Mexico
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => El poder secreto
            [country] => Uruguay
        ) 
)
```

As you can see, when there is the same title for lot of countries the array gets simplified by adding those countries to the same [country] index of the corresponding [title].

**How would you do it?**

Comment: I believe more context is required here, a simple solution for what you have provided would be impossible

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way of performing this exact task. Just give it a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming $spanish_countries is an array of spanish speaking countries...

```
foreach ( $array as $a ) {
    if ( in_array($a['country'], $spanish_countries) ) {
        $final_array[$a['title']][] = $a['country'];
    }
}
```

this will result in a different array at the end but would be trivial to get to your format

---

Edit for comment

```
foreach ( $final_array as $k => $v ) {
  $r[] = array(
    'title'   => $k,
    'country' => implode(', ', $v)
  );
}
print_r($r);
```

youll want better variable names, but this will work

Comment: Hi! im getting this:
Array (
    [Los secretos del poder] => Array
        (
            [0] => Argentina
            [1] => Mexico
            [2] => Uruguay
        )

    [La sombra del poder] => Array
        (
            [0] => Spain
        )
)

How can i get the movie title inside a [title] index??

Comment: Great@! thanks, its working.. I wonder if there is a way to simplify those two foreachs in one thing? sorry but im new in php :)

Comment: both steps are needed. first steps groups the items by title. second step creates the array in the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$input  = array( /* your data */ );
$output = $tmp = array();

foreach ( $input as $v ) {
  if ( !isset($tmp[$v['title']]) {
    $tmp[$v['title']] = array();
  }

  // here you can check if your counry is spanish speaking
  if ( !in_array($v['country'], $spanishSpeakingCountries) ) {
    continue;
  }

  $tmp[$v['title']][] = $v['country'];
}

foreach ( $tmp as $k => $v ) {
  $output[] = array(
    'title'   => $k,
    'country' => implode(', ', $v)
  );
}

$output; // your output data
```

Comment: im getting a parse error here: 

foreach ( $input as $v ) {
  if ( !isset($tmp[$v['title']]) {

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($yourarray as $data)
{
    $newlist[$data['title']][] = $data['country'];
}
```

This would give you

```
Array (
    ['Los secretos del poder'] => Array
        (
            [0] => Argentina
            [1] => Mexico
        )
    ['El poder secreto'] => Array
        (
            [0] => Uruguay
        ) 
)
```

Comment: you forgot to check if the country was spanish speaking!